# typescript .d.ts module for images not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I am a little new to Typescript my only weakness is the `tsconfig.json`.

I have a problem with importing images ( in Reactjs ) being not found:

```sh
client/app/Reports/View.tsx:11:30 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../assets/images/placeholders/awards.png' or its corresponding type declarations.

11 import AwardPlaceholder from "../../assets/images/placeholders/awards.png";
```

So I searched and found a conclusion to declare modules for the image files so TS can register them as modules properly, so I did this:

```js
// @types/images.d.ts
declare module '*.svg' {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}

declare module '*.png' {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}

declare module '*.jpg' {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}
```

but the error still persists, here is my `tsconfig.json`, I think it could use some work but this is working how I want it to because I have custom type declartions

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "target": "es2017",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "jsx": "react",
        "paths": {
         "MyCustomTypesModule" : ["@types/MyCustomTypesModule/index.d.ts"],
            "*": [
                "node_modules/*"
            ]
        },
        "typeRoots" : ["@types"]
    },
    "include": [
        "server/**/*",
        "client/**/*"
    ]
}
```

through my research, since the `images.d.ts` declaration file is in my `@types` folder, Typescript should just see and acknowledge it.

Is something wrong with my `tsconfig.json`? Do I have to register it seperately in the config somewhere?

To run the typescript server, I just execute `$ tsc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I moved my `images.d.ts` from the path of `@types/images.d.ts` to outside of my `@types` folder to `client/images.d.ts` and somehow it worked even though my `typeRoots` is `[@types]`.

Comment: Typescript is so bloody weird. It's insanely useful, if it works, otherwise it's a HUGE pain in the arse.

Answer (score 2):

The key thing for me was that the `.d.ts` files need to be in *subfolders* within `@types`.

My folder structure now looks like this and works perfectly:

```
my_project/
├─ @types/
│  ├─ global/
│  │  ├─ index.d.ts
│  ├─ assets/
│  │  ├─ index.d.ts
├─ app.tsx
```

Comment: thanks for the tip. and yes once Typescript works it is great to have. the setup is indeed a pain